# Does flaked rye need conversion?

Tags: beer, mash, rye

I'm looking to make a rye pale ale. Do I need to provide enough base grains to convert the starches in flaked rye or is it capable of self conversion? If it needs conversion, would 6 lbs of 6-row work for 2.5 lbs of rye?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flaked rye needs to be converted.  6 lbs of either 2-row or 6-row would be plenty to convert 2.5lbs of rye.

Answer (score 2):

Flaked rye (unmalted) has a low diastatic power, so it would definitely need some base malt (6-row would work fine) for starch conversion.

However, generally flaked rye is used for taste, and not as much for its starch content. If you are doing a mash anyway, you might as well throw it in, <strike>but if you are using it to flavor an extract brew, you can just steep it as you would any other specialty grain.</strike>

Edit: Thanks Denny, you are definitely right on this. Don't steep, do a partial mash if you want rye in an extract brew.

Comment: Steeping flaked rye (or any other flaked grain) will add unconverted starch to your beer.  That's not a good thing.  Not only does it not taste good, it can provide food for bacteria which can infect your beer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use 2 row instead of 6 row unless you want the grainy flavor you get from 6 row.  You don't need 6 row for enzymes.  2 row has plenty of diastatic power without having to resort to 6 row.